# Decode JSON String decode returning null

Tags: php, json

I am tying to pass this jsonString to my query

```
xxxxxx=createVenue&clientId=2&jsonString={"veneue":{"clientId":"b","name":"d","tagline":"f","phone":"b","address":"d","city":"f","state":"b","zip":"d","twitter":"f","license":"d","imagePath":"f","pickupLocation":"b"},"drinks":[{"type":"d","name":"f","servingTable":{"servingSize":"b","price":"d"}},{"type":"d","name":"f","servingTable":{"servingSize":"b","price":"d"}}],"spirits":[{"type":"d","name":"f","servingTable":{"servingSize":"b","price":"d"}},{"type":"d","name":"f","servingTable":{"servingSize":"b","price":"d"}}]}
```

But when i decode it in php it returns null.

```
$clientId = trim($_REQUEST['clientId']);
        $jsonString = trim($_REQUEST['jsonString']);
        $decodedJSON = json_decode($jsonString);

        return $decodedJSON;
```

$decodedJSON Returns null;

What is wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried `urldecode()` before `json_decode()`?

Comment: Hint: *inspect* the value of `trim($_REQUEST['jsonString'])` (and run it through a validator to find out exactly which part[s] are now invalid)

Comment: whats the point of down voting?

Comment: you should NOT be passing "long" data like that in the query string. Most servers restrict how long a query string can be and can silently chop off the end of the string, leaving you with a corrupted json string that will never decode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json seems to be valid.
Probably the quotes get escaped with backslashes because you have magic_quotes_gpc turned on. What you need to do is to use

```
$jsonString = trim(stripslashes ($_REQUEST['jsonString']));
```

Comment: that fixed it really thanks....Simple request was returning colons turned into slashes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, found it after trying to figure out for like 2h, what the issue is...as it was input field, quotes were escaped. How would you be able to see this during debugging so that i know for future?

Answer (score 1):

before parsing try to output value like `die(trim($_REQUEST['jsonString']));` - you will see that string corrupted

so problem in place where this string is inserted into url, in that place you should do `urlencode(json_encode(...))`